# Statements wrapped in curly braces problems

Tags: javascript

I found that in javascript if we write in console

```
var i = 5;
{
  i = 6;
}
var b;
```

Why it is spitting 6 and if I write something like:

```
{
t:33
}
```

Where the variable t stores and how to access it?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: why first bock is giving 6 as output?

Comment: I've never seen a JS code block like this, not sure what you expect this to do

Comment: "Why it is spitting 6" makes no sense. `t` will be a **global variable** since JS doesn't have block scope and you haven't put the `var` keyword in front of the variable name.

Comment: Curly braces don't create a new scope, only functions create a new scope. Curly braces is also a shorthand for `new Object()`

Comment: Your code btw is exactly same as `var i = 5;i = 6;`

Comment: what about if is `let i = 6;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this:

```
var i = 5;
{
  i = 6;
}
var b;
```

Is the same as writing this:

```
var i = 5;
i = 6;
var b;
```

Variable declarations are not logged into the console, only asignments, so you'll see the `6` from the `i=6` asignment. (i=6 returns the asigned value, the `var` declaration does not)

In the second case you create an object which has a key `t`

Comment: Can we access t in any case?

Comment: You can't because you didn't save any reference to the object created, thus it is garbage collected. If you save a reference to that object, such as `var obj = {t:3}` you can then write `obj.t`